# play sound for notification when user added new data to database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to play a sound when user have succesfully added new data to database in codeigniter

**This is the form for insert data**

```
 <form name="frmNotification" id="frmNotification" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>home/postcomment" method="post" >
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control w-100" name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="9" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Message'" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject'" placeholder="Enter Subject">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-element">
                <input type="submit" name="add" id="btn-send" value="Submit">
            </div>
                    </form>
```

**and this is the controller Home.php**

```
public function postcomment()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment','Commment','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject','Subject','required');
    if($this->form_validation->run() != false){
    $comment = $this->input->post('comment');
    $subject = $this->input->post('subject');

    $data = array(
        'comment' => $comment,
        'subject' => $subject
        );
    $this->m_comment->input_data($data,'comments');
    $_SESSION['pesan'] = 'Data berhasil di kirim';
    redirect('home/contact');

    }else{
        $this->load->view('web/contact',$data);
    }
}
```

**And this is the model**

```
function input_data($data,$table){
    $this->db->insert($table,$data);
}
```

Comment: Load up a sound on the success page, after the form's submitted.

Comment: Maybe play a midi with `bgsound`.